# Name of a popular children's game

Tags: riddle, word

Given the following clues...what is the name of the children's game?

**The 3rd person present**

**Will determine the one**

**You always get lost with**

Hint:

> Only three words long

Hint #2:

> Gracie Allen said "George is the ________ and I will never get lost without him!"

If you get hint #2 you will instantly know the answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is

> Follow the leader

As,

The third person present here denote the

> Leader (neither the person who says / nor listens - belong to this)

Will determine the one

> Is the definitive / determining article of English language - **THE**

You always get lost with

> is of course, the leader, whom you follow (blindly, sometimes)

Comment: YES!!!!!!!   Yay!!  Correct!!!!   Whoopeeeee!  One tiny little catch is that "follow" is the 3rd person present....

Answer (score 3):

> Hide and seek.

Because

> When three person play it, let's say A, B, C, then C will try to search for A and B, who are "lost", thus determining the one you(one of A or B) get lost with.

Comment: As a go player I must oppose the word count here :-)

Comment: @Nopalaa  I appreciate the analysis and conclusion.  However you are not close.  Hint:  'Hide' would not be 3rd person present...  Actually...I just checked and 'Hide" is a 3rd person present...  That should help.  On the other hand 'and' doesn't determine anything...

Comment: further hint:  'Hide' is not the correct 3rd person present

Answer (score 0):

How about

> Duck, Duck, Goose

because

> The 3rd person present determining the one refers to the person who is "it" designating the "goose" (3rd in the name). They both run around the ring of players ("get lost").

Comment: Ahhh, by the hint to Nopalaa it seems that the second word, from the second line of the hint needs to be a "determiner" and Duck would not fit that "bill".  Duck is also not a 3rd person present.  It is a noun...

Comment: Ah well. I was trying a solution where 1 line didn't necessarily map to one word. +1 for "bill" though

Comment: the 'bill' was blatant taking advantage of an opportunity at a bad pun.  mapping one line of the clue to a word is a good idea here.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's

> Mother May I

Because

> "Mother" is the 'third party' present. It can also be a verb 'to mother' in the present tense.
>  "May" implies someone is deciding whether an action is acceptable.
>  "I" -- no matter how lost I get, "I" am always there.

Comment: Not correct but definitely making progress.  Your thinking on the first part is on the right track.  And your thinking in the last part is on the right track.  I will add another hint...Have a look above